# How do I use the POST of Laravel's Route::resource?

Tags: php, rest, laravel, laravel-4, routes

Below is my code for a Laravel 4 project.

Going to the authors/create URL and submitting the form gives me a 405 error. 
However, if I prepend the `routes.php` file with `Route::post('authors/store', 'AuthorsController@store');`, basically doubling what it already should do, everything works like a charm!

Why do I need do prepend said line in my code to work? I can only assume I'm doing something wrong here.

routes.php:

```
Route::resource('authors', 'AuthorsController');
```

AuthorsController.php:

```
public function create() {
    $view = View::make('authors.create');
    return $view;
}

public function store() {
    //
}
```

authors/create.twig:

```
{{ form_open({'url':'authors/store'},{"method" : "post"}) }}
<p>
{{ form_label("Name", "name") }}
{{ form_text("name") }}
</p>
<p>
    {{ form_submit("Add Author") }}
</p>
{{ form_close() }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `store` action get's trigger when you POST to the resource. So just `authors` and not `authors/store`:

```
{{ form_open({'url':'authors'},{"method" : "post"}) }}
```

See [this table](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers) on more information what URL corresponds to what controller action.

Also I think it should be like this:

```
{{ form_open({'url':'authors', 'method' : 'post'}) }}
```

And you can pass the route name Laravel automatically generates to make your life a bit easier:

```
{{ form_open({'route':'authors.store', 'method' : 'post'}) }}
```

Oh and one more, `post` is the default method so this should do as well:

```
{{ form_open({'route':'authors.store'}) }}
```

Comment: Sometimes it's just that easy. Thanks.